# React Navigation this.props.navigation.navigate doesn't navigate to the next screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have an `Authentication` screen like this :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Profile from './Profile';
import LoginOrSignup from './LoginOrSignup';

class Auth extends Component {
  render() {
    if (this.props.isLoggedIn) {
        return <Profile />;
    } else {
        return <LoginOrSignup />;
    }
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
   return {
      isLoggedIn: state.auth.isLoggedIn
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Auth);
```

On my `LoginOrSignup` screen i have a `submit` button contains a function to navigate like this:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("ConfirmOTP");
```

But I always got this error :

> undefined is not an object(evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate')

Then I tried to changed my `Authentication` screen like this

```
.....
<LoginOrSignup navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
.....
```

The error is gone, but it doesn't navigate to the next screen.
I'm still learning. Any helps would be really appreciated.

Comment: Share your `LoginOrSignup` code

Answer (score 0):

you need to register your sreen to a Route. This can be an example using createStackNavigator of react-navigation.

```
import ConfirmOtp from "./ConfirmOtp";
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation";

class LoginOrSignup extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View> 
                <Button onClick={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("ConfirmOtp")}/>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

export default createStackNavigator({
    LoginOrSignup {
        screen: LoginOrSignup
    },
    ConfirmOtp: {
        screen: ConfirmOtp
    }
});
```